# Why does returning this ECMAScript Harmony arrow function expression produce unexpected behavior?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony, arrow-functions

I've been playing with the new ECMAScript 6 features and this question has to do with arrow functions. The following code is a simple functional composition method assigned to the `Function` object's prototype. It works perfectly well using a simple anonymous function but does not when using an arrow function instead.

```
Function.prototype.compose = function (bar) {
    var foo = this;
    return function () {
        return foo(bar.apply(null, arguments));
    };
};

var addFive = function (baz) {
    return baz + 5;
};

var addTen = function (hello) {
    return hello + 10;
};

var addFifteen = addFive.compose(addTen);

console.log(addFifteen(10));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oegonbmn/

```
Function.prototype.compose = function (bar) {
    var foo = this;
    return () => foo(bar.apply(null, arguments));
};

var addFive = function (baz) {
    return baz + 5;
};

var addTen = function (hello) {
    return hello + 10;
};

var addFifteen = addFive.compose(addTen);

console.log(addFifteen(10));
```

http://www.es6fiddle.com/hyo32b2p/

The first one logs `25` correctly to the console whereas the second one logs function `(hello) { return hello + 10; }105` which doesn't exactly tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I am not returning the value within the arrow function since it is supposed to implicitly return the very last statement (the first and last in this instance) and I suppose the issue at hand has something to do with the lexical scoping and the values of this, maybe. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `this` and `arguments` are not (re)bound in arrow functions, but instead lexically scoped. That is, you get whatever they are bound to in the surrounding scope.

In ES6, using `arguments` is deprecated anyway. The preferred solution is to use rest parameters:

```
Function.prototype.compose = function (bar) {
  return (...args) => this(bar.apply(null, args));
};
```

or, in fact:

```
Function.prototype.compose = function (bar) {
  return (...args) => this(bar(...args));
};
```

Comment: Okay. This is great. Thank you. One last question. Does this mean that there is no arguments property on arrow functions? Or that the arguments property is bound to the value of the arguments property of the surrounding function or in case of no function, undefined?

Comment: The arguments _property_ on functions is a broken legacy misfeature, which, for good reasons, has never been standardised. I don't think any VM vendor has the intention of proliferating it to arrow functions. It will simply not exist.

Comment: Neither will `.caller` and `.callee`, btw.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you! So to access parameters besides named ones, the rest parameters are a best practice from ES6 onwards. Am I correct?